Is the imaginary unit $i$ contained in $\mathbb{Q}(e+i)$?
Is the imaginary unit $i$ contained in $\mathbb{Q}(e+i)$? $i \in \mathbb{Q}(e+i)$? Intuition tells me $i$ is not contained in $\mathbb{Q}(e+i)$ because it should somehow contradict the fact that $e$ is transcendent over $\mathbb{Q}$. But I can't seem to find a proof, so I might be wrong.

Your question is equivalent to:

Does the field $\Bbb Q(X)$ contain an element whose square equals $-1$?

The answer is no, since this field can be embedded in $\Bbb R$.
Edit. Here is a more elementary proof (by contradiction). If, for some $m,n\in\Bbb N$, $i\sum_{k=0}^mb_k(e+i)^k=\sum_{k=0}^na_k(e+i)^k$ with $a_0,\dots,a_n,b_0,\dots,b_m\in\Bbb Q$ and $a_n,b_m\ne0$, then (since $e$ is transcendental over $\Bbb Q[i]$) $m=n$ and $ib_m=a_m$, which is absurd.

$\mathbb{Q}(e+i)$, not $\mathbb{Q}[e+i]$.

If one were to apply this argument to the question, one would need to embed $\mathbb{Q}(e+i)$ in $\mathbb{R}$.

@ameg No problem: since $e+i$ is transcendental, $\mathbb{Q}(e+i)\cong\mathbb{Q}(x)\cong \mathbb{Q}(\pi)$. You can replace $\pi$ with any real transcendental number.

I don't understand why the fact that $\mathbb{Q}(e+i)$ can be embedded in $\mathbb{R}$ implies it cannot contain an element whose square is -1.

@AlexKruckman The issue is not whether one can do it, but whether an argument that hides what is important is useful at all.

@AnneBauval I see. And could you please specify the embedding that you are referring to? The fact that there is an embedding means there is an isomorphism?

@Rainbow For any trancendental number $\alpha$, the map $\Bbb Q(X)\to\Bbb Q(\alpha),;f(X)\mapsto f(\alpha)$ is an isomorphism, and if $\alpha\in\Bbb R$ then $\Bbb Q(\alpha)\subset\Bbb R$.

@AnneBauval I am sorry if this is obvious, but I don't understand how you are defining the embedding from $Q(X)$ to $Q(\alpha)$. An embedding is an injective homomorphism, right? In order to define it, you must choose where to send each element in $\mathbb{Q}(X)=\mathbb{Q}(e+i) \neq \mathbb{Q}[e+i]$, so it is unclear to me what those elements are and where you are sending them.

@AnneBauval Thank you! I wasn't familiar with the field of rational fractions. Since isomorphisms satisfy the transitive property, the fact that $\mathbb{Q}(e+i)$ is isomoprhic to $f(X)$ and $f(X)$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Q}(\pi) \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ implies that $\mathbb{Q}(e+i)$ is isomorphic to a subfield of $\mathbb{R}$. Right?

@AnneBauval In your new attempt you suppose by contradiction that $i\in \mathbb{Q}(e+i)$. This means that, if $p(x)\in \mathbb{Q}[x]$, then $i,p(e+i) \in \mathbb{Q}(e+i)$. Since $\mathbb{Q}(e+i)$ is a field, $ip(e+i) \in \mathbb{Q}(e+i)$. But that does not mean $ip(e+i)=q(e+i)$ for some $q(e+i)\in \mathbb{Q}[e+i]$ because $\mathbb{Q}[e+i] \neq \mathbb{Q}(e+i)$. Right? Could your second attempt be wrong?

$i\in\Bbb Q(e+i)$ doesn't mean what you wrote. It means that there exist two nonzero polynomials $P(X)=\sum a_kX^k,Q(X)=\sum b_kX^k\in\Bbb Q[X]$ such that $iQ(e+i)=P(e+i)$.

@AnneBauval But why? As far as I know, $\mathbb{Q}(e+i)$ is just the smallest field containing $\mathbb{Q}$ and $e+i$. Why would belonging to $\mathbb{Q}(e+i)$ imply what you have written above?

See this comment. More explicitely: a field containing $\Bbb Q$ and $e+i$ necessarily contains ${f(e+i)\mid f\in\Bbb Q(X)}$, which turns out to be a field.
